# Removing Percent Encoding from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

The firebase function I'm currently using retrieves data from a certain branch in the database where the value may or may not have percent encoding. The value is a user's username and it's encoded if there's a '.' in the name. When the user gets a notification, it has their name in the body of it, and I'm trying to figure out how to removePercentEncoding if necessary. My cloud function:

```
 exports.newPost = functions.database.ref('/{school}/posts').onWrite((change, context) => {
          const school = context.params.school
          const postUsername = admin.database().ref('/{school}/lastPost/lastPostUser').once('value')
        var db = admin.database();

        var val1, val2;
      db.ref(`/Herrick Middle School/lastPost/lastPostUser`).once('value').then(snap => {
        val1 = snap.val();
        console.log(snap.val());

        return val1
      }).then(() => {
        return db.ref("test2/val").once('value');
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });


          return loadUsers().then(users => {
            let tokens = [];
            for (let user of users) {
                tokens.push(user.pushToken);
                console.log(`pushToken: ${user.pushToken}`);
            }

            let payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: school,
                    body: `${val1} just posted something.`,
                    sound: 'Apex',
                    badge: '1'
                }
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        });
    });


    function loadUsers() {
      let dbRef = admin.database().ref('/Herrick Middle School/regisTokens');
      let defer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dbRef.once('value', (snap) => {
          let data = snap.val();
          let users = [];
              for (var property in data) {
                  users.push(data[property]);
                  console.log(`data: ${property}`);
                }
                resolve(users);
              }, (err) => {
                reject(err);
                });
              });
            return defer;
          }
```

More specifically, I was hoping someone could shed some light on how to remove encoding from

> val

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand but either native JS `decodeURI()` or regex like this

```js
var encoded = "john%doe%doe%bird";
console.log(encoded.replace(/%/g, "."));
```

Comment: It works for putting the periods in. What I neglected to include in the question was that the method in Swift I use for encoding includes basically everything: spaces, periods, brackets, slashes, etc. The encode for a period in percent encoding is %20. Also, when I ran is in the console this is what came out: Allce.20this.20boy - I guess what I'm trying to ask is, is there a broader term for decoding instead of just one symbol? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know of `encodeURI()` and `decodeURI()` to handle URI strings, and there's also a `btoa` built in for basic auth header creation?... Hope that helps. Good luck!